# Why do I need a $watch when using function in controller in combination with a directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-controller

I know and can imagine why I need the commented lines of code to let this work. But I can't found the technical reason. Why is the field not update when you click on the button? (the `$watch` fixed the problem. See comments)

Code:

```js
angular.module('app', []).directive('foo', function() {
    return {
            scope: {
                value: '='
            },
            link: function($scope, element){
              element.html($scope.value);
              //$scope.$watch(function() { return $scope.value }, function(){
               //element.html($scope.value);
               //})             
            }
        };
}).controller('FooController', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.bar = "Hi"

   $scope.sayHallo = function(){
     return $scope.bar;
    }
    
    $scope.changeHallo = function(){
     $scope.bar = "Héj";
    }
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app">
    <div ng-controller="FooController">
        <div foo value="sayHallo()" ></div>
        <button ng-click="changeHallo()">
            Click
        </button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: check out this https://jsfiddle.net/9rgyj8gp/

Answer (score 4):

A watch is needed in your use case.

A directive doesn't go through the link function every time one of the scope variables change. So with the watch commented out the link function will get executed and the html of the element will be set and that's the end of the link function. It doesn't get executed any more for that instance of the directive.

So if you want to update the html of the element every time the scope variable changes you will need a watcher.

Answer (score 0):

This change may help you

**HTML**

```
<div ng-controller="FooController">
    <div foo value="bar"></div>
    <button ng-click="changeHallo()">
      Click
    </button>
  </div>
```

[Jsfiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/9rgyj8gp/)

Comment: Yes this works ofcourse but that doesn't anwer the question. The `sayHallo()` function is just a simple example . The real code function is way more complex

Comment: actually in that case function never get called, and as you have created isolated scope in directive so either you can use `&` to bind out side function

Answer (score 0):

```
//if you don't want to use watch please use as below
element.bind('click', function () {
    //your code

    //after your code    
    scope.$digest();
});
```